# How to set up atom editor for clojurescript development with figwheel?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, atom-editor, figwheel

It looks like the atom editor has a reasonable degree of clojure and clojurescript support through various packages. **Does anyone have a recommended way to configure it to use figwheel?** Clearly this is possible using a separate terminal, but I'm interested in whether a more integrated in-edit REPL is possible. One where the REPL executes code in the browser app.

I'm looking for some help akin to that provided at https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Running-figwheel-in-a-Cursive-Clojure-REPL for the intellij/cursive ide.

Update: After reading [Using the Figwheel REPL within NRepl](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Using-the-Figwheel-REPL-within-NRepl), and realising that the 'Start REPL' command provided by the atom package [proto-repl](https://atom.io/packages/proto-repl) probably ran `lein repl`, I updated my project accordingly - [see gist](https://gist.github.com/gmp26/36088dbadaca074869ffdc1fc4016bef#file-project-clj).

Start REPL produced some promising output [see gist](https://gist.github.com/gmp26/36088dbadaca074869ffdc1fc4016bef#file-output-from-start-repl-txt), and the application started correctly in the browser.

Almost there! This works, but so far I have not found a way to free up port 3449 again. Not even closing down the editor and restarting does that.

Here's the issue

```
user=> nil
(stop-figwheel!)
user=> nil
(start-figwheel!)
Figwheel: Starting server at http://127.0.0.1:3450
Port 3450 is already being used. 
Are you running another Figwheel instance? 
If you want to run two Figwheel instances add a new :server-port (i.e.:server-port 3450)
to Figwheel's config options in your project.clj
```

Comment: OK - I was on the right track.  The [intellij instructions]( https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Running-figwheel-in-a-Cursive-Clojure-REPL) work for atom too with two minor changes:

1. You need to arrange to call the commands in the script/repl.clj file somehow after nrepl connects.

2. You need to add a dependency on proto-repl to project.clj.


[Here is the project]() I configured to use atom.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is being discussed in issue 54 on the [proto-repl repo](https://github.com/jasongilman/proto-repl/issues/54), and as yet there is no solution.